# Headless crash every 1-7 days

Tags: networking, server, nfs

I have a headless Ubuntu server which reliably crashes every 1-7 days. It crashed on 5/1, and then again on 5/3 at about 8:30 am local time. I have scanned the logs for information but there's nothing forthcoming. Here is the relevant snippet of /var/log/syslog:

```
May  3 07:12:13 marvin snapd[879]: autorefresh.go:397: auto-refresh: all snaps are up-to-date
May  3 07:17:01 marvin CRON[23226]: (root) CMD (   cd / && run-parts --report /etc/cron.hourly)
May  3 07:30:01 marvin CRON[28582]: (root) CMD ([ -x /etc/init.d/anacron ] && if [ ! -d /run/systemd/system ]; then /usr/sbin/invoke-rc.d anacron start >/dev/null; fi)
May  3 08:04:23 marvin systemd[1]: Started Run anacron jobs.
May  3 08:04:23 marvin anacron[10633]: Anacron 2.3 started on 2020-05-03
May  3 08:04:23 marvin anacron[10633]: Normal exit (0 jobs run)
May  3 08:17:01 marvin CRON[15912]: (root) CMD (   cd / && run-parts --report /etc/cron.hourly)
May  3 14:23:35 marvin systemd-modules-load[290]: Inserted module 'lp'
May  3 14:23:35 marvin systemd-modules-load[290]: Inserted module 'ppdev'
May  3 14:23:35 marvin systemd-modules-load[290]: Inserted module 'parport_pc'
May  3 14:23:35 marvin systemd[1]: Started Uncomplicated firewall.
May  3 14:23:35 marvin systemd[1]: Started Load Kernel Modules.
```

The log lines at 14:23 are when I got home and managed to restart the server. When it is "crashed", the power light is still on but it doesn't respond to pings, and connecting a monitor shows nothing on the screen.

The server is just used as a Plex media server, streaming video from a NAS which is mounted with NFS. Plex is running in a Docker container, and I have a few other small containers running like OpenVPN. I'm running Ubuntu 18.04.4. I don't know if this is helpful, but here's a dump of my hardware:

```
max@marvin:~$ sudo lshw -short
H/W path      Device           Class          Description
=========================================================
                               system         To Be Filled By O.E.M. (To Be Filled By O.E.M.)
/0                             bus            H110M-STX
/0/0                           memory         64KiB BIOS
/0/8                           memory         128KiB L1 cache
/0/9                           memory         128KiB L1 cache
/0/a                           memory         1MiB L2 cache
/0/b                           memory         8MiB L3 cache
/0/c                           processor      Intel(R) Core(TM) i7-6700K CPU @ 4.00GHz
/0/d                           memory         16GiB System Memory
/0/d/0                         memory         8GiB SODIMM DDR4 Synchronous 2133 MHz (0.5 ns)
/0/d/1                         memory         8GiB SODIMM DDR4 Synchronous 2133 MHz (0.5 ns)
/0/100                         bridge         Xeon E3-1200 v5/E3-1500 v5/6th Gen Core Processor Host Bridge/DRAM Registers
/0/100/1                       bridge         Xeon E3-1200 v5/E3-1500 v5/6th Gen Core Processor PCIe Controller (x16)
/0/100/1/0                     storage        NVMe SSD Controller SM961/PM961
/0/100/2                       display        HD Graphics 530
/0/100/14                      bus            100 Series/C230 Series Chipset Family USB 3.0 xHCI Controller
/0/100/14/0   usb1             bus            xHCI Host Controller
/0/100/14/1   usb2             bus            xHCI Host Controller
/0/100/14.2                    generic        100 Series/C230 Series Chipset Family Thermal Subsystem
/0/100/16                      communication  100 Series/C230 Series Chipset Family MEI Controller #1
/0/100/17                      storage        Q170/Q150/B150/H170/H110/Z170/CM236 Chipset SATA Controller [AHCI Mode]
/0/100/1c                      bridge         100 Series/C230 Series Chipset Family PCI Express Root Port #5
/0/100/1f                      bridge         H110 Chipset LPC/eSPI Controller
/0/100/1f.2                    memory         Memory controller
/0/100/1f.3                    multimedia     100 Series/C230 Series Chipset Family HD Audio Controller
/0/100/1f.4                    bus            100 Series/C230 Series Chipset Family SMBus
/0/100/1f.6   enp0s31f6        network        Ethernet Connection (2) I219-V
/0/1          scsi1            storage
/0/1/0.0.0    /dev/sda         disk           500GB Samsung SSD 860
/0/1/0.0.0/1  /dev/sda1        volume         465GiB EXT4 volume
```

I am somewhat at my wit's end trying to figure it out, so any assistance would be much appreciated.

EDIT 1: Adding output of `ls -la /var/crash`. There's nothing in there.

```
max@marvin:~$ ls -la /var/crash
total 8
drwxrwsrwt  2 root whoopsie 4096 Oct 14  2019 .
drwxr-xr-x 15 root root     4096 May  3  2018 ..
```

EDIT 2: Additional info. I have noticed that sometimes `sensors` reports very different values just a couple of seconds apart. The two outputs below were run back-to-back.

```
max@marvin:~$ sudo dmidecode -s bios-version
P1.10

max@marvin:~$ sensors
pch_skylake-virtual-0
Adapter: Virtual device
temp1:        +53.5°C

coretemp-isa-0000
Adapter: ISA adapter
Package id 0:  +58.0°C  (high = +80.0°C, crit = +100.0°C)
Core 0:        +44.0°C  (high = +80.0°C, crit = +100.0°C)
Core 1:        +47.0°C  (high = +80.0°C, crit = +100.0°C)
Core 2:        +58.0°C  (high = +80.0°C, crit = +100.0°C)
Core 3:        +43.0°C  (high = +80.0°C, crit = +100.0°C)

max@marvin:~$ sensors
pch_skylake-virtual-0
Adapter: Virtual device
temp1:        +53.5°C

coretemp-isa-0000
Adapter: ISA adapter
Package id 0:  +44.0°C  (high = +80.0°C, crit = +100.0°C)
Core 0:        +40.0°C  (high = +80.0°C, crit = +100.0°C)
Core 1:        +42.0°C  (high = +80.0°C, crit = +100.0°C)
Core 2:        +38.0°C  (high = +80.0°C, crit = +100.0°C)
Core 3:        +39.0°C  (high = +80.0°C, crit = +100.0°C)
```

The computer is an ASRock DeskMini 110, with an i7-6700K, 16GB DDR4 2400MHz SODIMM Memory from Corsair, a Noctua NH-L9I (which is spinning fine), a 250GB Samsung 960 EVO NVME drive, and a 500GB Samsung SATA SSD (I think an 860 EVO, I can't quite recall).

Here's a grab of the output from `top`. If you'd rather an actual screenshot let me know.

```
top - 10:58:47 up 20:35,  2 users,  load average: 0.61, 0.37, 0.33
Tasks: 345 total,   1 running, 270 sleeping,   0 stopped,   0 zombie
%Cpu(s):  2.2 us,  0.8 sy,  0.0 ni, 96.9 id,  0.0 wa,  0.0 hi,  0.0 si,  0.0 st
KiB Mem : 16120772 total,   942036 free,  4121516 used, 11057220 buff/cache
KiB Swap:  2097148 total,   371812 free,  1725336 used. 11667140 avail Mem

  PID USER      PR  NI    VIRT    RES    SHR S  %CPU %MEM     TIME+ COMMAND
 7137 max       20   0 2872064 747632   3372 S  11.2  4.6 109:14.82 java
15027 root      20   0    4504    772    704 S   4.9  0.0   0:00.15 sh
 8826 911       20   0  508872  43296   4804 S   2.0  0.3  15:14.61 deluged
 6401 max       20   0 4612692 998252  18232 S   1.0  6.2  24:04.40 Plex Media Serv
 1184 root      20   0 3327792  26348  15320 S   0.7  0.2   6:23.03 containerd
 1321 root      20   0 4151696  49524  12680 S   0.7  0.3   6:49.66 dockerd
 6438 max       35  15 1862372 204256   5680 S   0.7  1.3   2:39.45 Plex Script Hos
 9831 911       20   0  147104 101632   6036 S   0.7  0.6  59:57.74 python3
22107 max       20   0   77320   6224   5324 S   0.7  0.0   3:07.15 systemd
    1 root      20   0  226000   8380   6008 S   0.3  0.1   4:22.96 systemd
  847 root      20   0   70704   5840   5020 S   0.3  0.0   0:52.57 systemd-logind
  873 message+  20   0   50848   4732   3336 S   0.3  0.0   2:54.19 dbus-daemon
 4441 root      20   0   11828   3384   2348 S   0.3  0.0   0:58.45 containerd-shim
 6894 911       20   0  603768  18392   4824 S   0.3  0.1   4:25.21 deluged
 8202 911       20   0  168528 102360   3364 S   0.3  0.6   4:43.52 python
10469 911       20   0 4918084 305300   6312 S   0.3  1.9 182:10.26 sabnzbdplus
    2 root      20   0       0      0      0 S   0.0  0.0   0:00.07 kthreadd
    4 root       0 -20       0      0      0 I   0.0  0.0   0:00.00 kworker/0:0H
    6 root       0 -20       0      0      0 I   0.0  0.0   0:00.00 mm_percpu_wq
    7 root      20   0       0      0      0 S   0.0  0.0   0:01.52 ksoftirqd/0
    8 root      20   0       0      0      0 I   0.0  0.0   0:39.70 rcu_sched
    9 root      20   0       0      0      0 I   0.0  0.0   0:00.00 rcu_bh
   10 root      rt   0       0      0      0 S   0.0  0.0   0:00.11 migration/0
   11 root      rt   0       0      0      0 S   0.0  0.0   0:00.11 watchdog/0
   12 root      20   0       0      0      0 S   0.0  0.0   0:00.00 cpuhp/0
   13 root      20   0       0      0      0 S   0.0  0.0   0:00.00 cpuhp/1
   14 root      rt   0       0      0      0 S   0.0  0.0   0:00.10 watchdog/1
   15 root      rt   0       0      0      0 S   0.0  0.0   0:00.14 migration/1
   16 root      20   0       0      0      0 S   0.0  0.0   0:01.34 ksoftirqd/1
   18 root       0 -20       0      0      0 I   0.0  0.0   0:00.00 kworker/1:0H
   19 root      20   0       0      0      0 S   0.0  0.0   0:00.00 cpuhp/2
   20 root      rt   0       0      0      0 S   0.0  0.0   0:00.12 watchdog/2
   21 root      rt   0       0      0      0 S   0.0  0.0   0:00.12 migration/2
   22 root      20   0       0      0      0 S   0.0  0.0   1:47.23 ksoftirqd/2
   24 root       0 -20       0      0      0 I   0.0  0.0   0:00.00 kworker/2:0H
   25 root      20   0       0      0      0 S   0.0  0.0   0:00.00 cpuhp/3
   26 root      rt   0       0      0      0 S   0.0  0.0   0:00.12 watchdog/3
   27 root      rt   0       0      0      0 S   0.0  0.0   0:00.14 migration/3
   28 root      20   0       0      0      0 S   0.0  0.0   0:01.39 ksoftirqd/3
   30 root       0 -20       0      0      0 I   0.0  0.0   0:00.00 kworker/3:0H
   31 root      20   0       0      0      0 S   0.0  0.0   0:00.00 cpuhp/4
   32 root      rt   0       0      0      0 S   0.0  0.0   0:00.11 watchdog/4
   33 root      rt   0       0      0      0 S   0.0  0.0   0:00.15 migration/4
   34 root      20   0       0      0      0 S   0.0  0.0   0:01.28 ksoftirqd/4
   36 root       0 -20       0      0      0 I   0.0  0.0   0:00.00 kworker/4:0H
   37 root      20   0       0      0      0 S   0.0  0.0   0:00.00 cpuhp/5
   38 root      rt   0       0      0      0 S   0.0  0.0   0:00.11 watchdog/5
   39 root      rt   0       0      0      0 S   0.0  0.0   0:00.14 migration/5
   40 root      20   0       0      0      0 S   0.0  0.0   0:01.19 ksoftirqd/5
   42 root       0 -20       0      0      0 I   0.0  0.0   0:00.00 kworker/5:0H
   43 root      20   0       0      0      0 S   0.0  0.0   0:00.00 cpuhp/6
   44 root      rt   0       0      0      0 S   0.0  0.0   0:00.12 watchdog/6
   45 root      rt   0       0      0      0 S   0.0  0.0   0:00.11 migration/6
   46 root      20   0       0      0      0 S   0.0  0.0   0:01.89 ksoftirqd/6
   48 root       0 -20       0      0      0 I   0.0  0.0   0:00.00 kworker/6:0H
   49 root      20   0       0      0      0 S   0.0  0.0   0:00.00 cpuhp/7
   50 root      rt   0       0      0      0 S   0.0  0.0   0:00.12 watchdog/7
   51 root      rt   0       0      0      0 S   0.0  0.0   0:00.14 migration/7
   52 root      20   0       0      0      0 S   0.0  0.0   0:01.23 ksoftirqd/7
   54 root       0 -20       0      0      0 I   0.0  0.0   0:00.00 kworker/7:0H
   55 root      20   0       0      0      0 S   0.0  0.0   0:00.00 kdevtmpfs
   56 root       0 -20       0      0      0 I   0.0  0.0   0:00.00 netns
   57 root      20   0       0      0      0 S   0.0  0.0   0:00.00 rcu_tasks_kthre
```

The `java` process at the top is a minecraft server; the machine has hung regardless of this running.

EDIT 3:

More info as requested.

```
max@marvin:/mnt/ssd/syrupy$ cat /etc/network/interfaces
# interfaces(5) file used by ifup(8) and ifdown(8)
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback

max@marvin:/mnt/ssd/syrupy$ cat /etc/netplan/*.yaml
# Let NetworkManager manage all devices on this system
network:
  version: 2
  renderer: NetworkManager
```

EDIT 4:

```
max@marvin:/etc$ ps auxc | grep -i therm
root       128  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        I<   10:19   0:00 acpi_thermal_pm
root       858  0.0  0.0 187000  9336 ?        Ssl  10:19   0:02 thermald
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: One trick: Leave 'top' running in an ssh window. When the server crashes, you will have a snapshot of what was pushing it off the cliff. I discovered a runaway Plex thumbnailer that way.

Comment: That's an incredibly good idea, I'll do so. I do have thumbnails turned on. I'll have to check if any new content was added around when it dies. How did you fix it in the end?

Comment: Fixing it is still on my to-do list. I turned off the thumbnailer until then.

Comment: Can you describe what the output of your `top` looked like when it died?

Comment: If I recall correctly, it froze at 99% CPU by a process called "plex-thumbnailer" or similar (and 1% CPU by a process called 'top'...well, we know that wasn't the culprit). That told me where to start looking. Of course, your problem may be quite different.

Comment: Edit your question and show me `ls -al /var/crash`. Start comments to me with @heynnema or I may miss them.

Comment: @heynnema Thanks for looking into this! There's nothing in /var/crash, but I have added the output as requested.

Comment: This is going to be a little difficult to troubleshoot... but here goes... your syslog snippet only appears to indicate that the system may be rebooting itself. Do you know what your CPU temps are? Is this a desktop machine? Are all of your fans working? Install lm-sensors if you don't have it. Show me `sensors`. Show me `sudo dmidecode -s bios-version` and tell me the exact make/model of your computer or motherboard. Also show me a screenshot of `top`.

Comment: @heynnema I have added additional info as request. Again, many thanks.

Comment: @heynnema If I wanted to upload an entire syslog, is there a way I can do that? Or shall I just copy/paste the contents of it into the post? Or upload it to pastebin or something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**BIOS**

**Note**: have good backups before performing a BIOS update

You have BIOS P1.10. If I'm reading the ASRock website correctly, version 8.10 is current. Please check [here](https://www.asrock.com/support/support.asp?Model=DeskMini%20110%20Series&cat=BIOS). Assure that this is the correct location for the BIOS update for your exact model #.

**Swap**

```
KiB Swap:  2097148 total,   371812 free,  1725336 used.
```

Your swap usage is high, and with only a 2G /swapfile, we probably need to increase it. There's also a slight chance that one of your applications is using such high swap.

If `grep -i swap /etc/fstab` shows this...

```
/swapfile    none    swap    sw      0   0
```

then you're using a /swapfile, instead of a swap partition.

Let's enlarge it from 2G to 4G...

**Note**: Incorrect use of the `dd` command can cause data loss. Suggest copy/paste.

```
sudo swapoff -a           # turn off swap
sudo rm -i /swapfile      # remove old /swapfile

sudo dd if=/dev/zero of=/swapfile bs=1M count=4096

sudo chmod 600 /swapfile  # set proper file protections
sudo mkswap /swapfile     # init /swapfile
sudo swapon /swapfile     # turn on swap
free -h                   # confirm 16G RAM and 4G swap
reboot                    # reboot and verify operation
```

**Samsung SSD**

If you have Windows, go to [here](https://www.samsung.com/semiconductor/minisite/ssd/download/tools/), and download their Samsung Magician, and check the firmware on your SSD's.

**Update #1:**

**NCQ error(s)**

`grep -i FPDMA /var/log/syslog*` to see if there's more of these...

```
May  7 12:29:22 marvin kernel: [   70.409155] ata2.00: exception Emask 0x10 SAct 0x1 SErr 0x400100 action 0x6 frozen
May  7 12:29:22 marvin kernel: [   70.409210] ata2.00: irq_stat 0x08000000, interface fatal error
May  7 12:29:22 marvin kernel: [   70.409246] ata2: SError: { UnrecovData Handshk }
May  7 12:29:22 marvin kernel: [   70.409276] ata2.00: failed command: WRITE FPDMA QUEUED
May  7 12:29:22 marvin kernel: [   70.409311] ata2.00: cmd 61/40:00:68:08:04/05:00:1d:00:00/40 tag 0 ncq dma 688128 out
May  7 12:29:22 marvin kernel: [   70.409311]          res 40/00:00:68:08:04/00:00:1d:00:00/40 Emask 0x10 (ATA bus error)
May  7 12:29:22 marvin kernel: [   70.409402] ata2.00: status: { DRDY }
May  7 12:29:22 marvin kernel: [   70.409426] ata2: hard resetting link
May  7 12:29:22 marvin kernel: [   70.723340] ata2: SATA link up 6.0 Gbps (SStatus 133 SControl 300)
May  7 12:29:22 marvin kernel: [   70.723562] ata2.00: supports DRM functions and may not be fully accessible
May  7 12:29:22 marvin kernel: [   70.725647] ata2.00: supports DRM functions and may not be fully accessible
May  7 12:29:22 marvin kernel: [   70.727418] ata2.00: configured for UDMA/133
May  7 12:29:22 marvin kernel: [   70.727430] ata2: EH complete
May  7 12:29:22 marvin kernel: [   70.727498] ata2.00: Enabling discard_zeroes_data
```

Native Command Queuing (NCQ) is an extension of the Serial ATA protocol allowing hard disk drives to internally optimize the order in which received read and write commands are executed.

Edit `sudo -H gedit /etc/default/grub` and change the following line to include this extra parameter. Then do `sudo update-grub` to write the changes to disk. Reboot. Monitor hangs, and watch `/var/log/syslog` or `dmesg` for continued error messages.

```
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash libata.force=noncq"
```

**postconf/postfix**

`grep -i postfix /var/log/syslog*` to see the hard postfix errors...

```
May  7 12:28:21 marvin ifup[787]: postconf: fatal: open /etc/postfix/main.cf: No such file or directory
```

**veth**

There's a LOT of veth* traffic in syslog. I don't know if it's normal. I'm not familiar with veth devices, but I believe it has to do with docker containers.

**Update #2:**

In reviewing today's syslog, here is what I noticed...

```
May 12 01:25:50 marvin kernel: [387411.971440] CPU5: Core temperature above threshold, cpu clock throttled (total events = 51751)
May 12 01:25:50 marvin kernel: [387411.971441] CPU1: Core temperature above threshold, cpu clock throttled (total events = 51751)
May 12 01:25:50 marvin kernel: [387411.971442] CPU4: Package temperature above threshold, cpu clock throttled (total events = 51751)
May 12 01:25:50 marvin kernel: [387411.971443] CPU6: Package temperature above threshold, cpu clock throttled (total events = 51751)
May 12 01:25:50 marvin kernel: [387411.971445] CPU3: Package temperature above threshold, cpu clock throttled (total events = 51751)
May 12 01:25:50 marvin kernel: [387411.971445] CPU7: Package temperature above threshold, cpu clock throttled (total events = 51751)
May 12 01:25:50 marvin kernel: [387411.971446] CPU0: Package temperature above threshold, cpu clock throttled (total events = 51751)
May 12 01:25:50 marvin kernel: [387411.971447] CPU2: Package temperature above threshold, cpu clock throttled (total events = 51750)
May 12 01:25:50 marvin kernel: [387411.971447] CPU1: Package temperature above threshold, cpu clock throttled (total events = 51751)
May 12 01:25:50 marvin kernel: [387411.971448] CPU5: Package temperature above threshold, cpu clock throttled (total events = 51751)
May 12 01:25:50 marvin kernel: [387411.973408] CPU5: Core temperature/speed normal
May 12 01:25:50 marvin kernel: [387411.973409] CPU1: Core temperature/speed normal
May 12 01:25:50 marvin kernel: [387411.973409] CPU3: Package temperature/speed normal
May 12 01:25:50 marvin kernel: [387411.973410] CPU7: Package temperature/speed normal
May 12 01:25:50 marvin kernel: [387411.973411] CPU4: Package temperature/speed normal
May 12 01:25:50 marvin kernel: [387411.973411] CPU0: Package temperature/speed normal
May 12 01:25:50 marvin kernel: [387411.973412] CPU5: Package temperature/speed normal
May 12 01:25:50 marvin kernel: [387411.973413] CPU1: Package temperature/speed normal
May 12 01:25:50 marvin kernel: [387411.973450] CPU6: Package temperature/speed normal
May 12 01:25:50 marvin kernel: [387411.973451] CPU2: Package temperature/speed normal
```

Check your fans.

---

and right before the reboot...

```
May 12 10:19:59 marvin blkmapd[310]: open pipe file /run/rpc_pipefs/nfs/blocklayout failed: No such file or directory
```

---

and during the reboot...

```
May 12 10:19:59 marvin kernel: [    2.720842] systemd[1]: /etc/systemd/system/docker.service.d/override.conf:2: Unknown lvalue 'After' in section 'Service'
```

Check for syntax errors in override.conf.

---

after the reboot...

```
May 12 10:19:59 marvin thermald[858]: sysfs read failed constraint_0_max_power_uw
```

In `terminal`, show me `ps auxc | grep -i therm`.

---

```
May 12 10:20:00 marvin nfsdcltrack[1019]: Failed to init database: -13
May 12 10:20:00 marvin systemd[1]: Started OpenBSD Secure Shell server.
May 12 10:20:00 marvin kernel: [    4.139130] NFSD: Using /var/lib/nfs/v4recovery as the NFSv4 state recovery directory
May 12 10:20:00 marvin kernel: [    4.139744] NFSD: starting 90-second grace period (net f00000a9)
May 12 10:20:00 marvin dbus-daemon[883]: [system] Successfully activated service 'org.freedesktop.nm_dispatcher'
```

---

Disk errors... check sata cable on ata2.00... download `Samsung Magician` from [here](https://www.samsung.com/semiconductor/minisite/ssd/download/tools/) and check your Samsung SSD's firmware...

```
May 12 10:21:01 marvin kernel: [   64.800038] ata2.00: exception Emask 0x10 SAct 0x0 SErr 0x400100 action 0x6 frozen
May 12 10:21:01 marvin kernel: [   64.800044] ata2.00: irq_stat 0x08000000, interface fatal error
May 12 10:21:01 marvin kernel: [   64.800047] ata2: SError: { UnrecovData Handshk }
May 12 10:21:01 marvin kernel: [   64.800050] ata2.00: failed command: WRITE DMA EXT
May 12 10:21:01 marvin kernel: [   64.800054] ata2.00: cmd 35/00:70:d0:55:61/00:01:0c:00:00/e0 tag 16 dma 188416 out
May 12 10:21:01 marvin kernel: [   64.800054]          res 50/00:00:cf:55:61/00:00:0c:00:00/e0 Emask 0x10 (ATA bus error)
May 12 10:21:01 marvin kernel: [   64.800059] ata2.00: status: { DRDY }
May 12 10:21:01 marvin kernel: [   64.800062] ata2: hard resetting link
May 12 10:21:01 marvin kernel: [   65.024521] eth0: renamed from veth43e132c
May 12 10:21:01 marvin NetworkManager[894]: <info>  [1589304061.8663] devices removed (path: /sys/devices/virtual/net/veth43e132c, iface: veth43e132c)
May 12 10:21:01 marvin NetworkManager[894]: <info>  [1589304061.8667] device (vethfcd015c): carrier: link connected
May 12 10:21:01 marvin kernel: [   65.048579] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_CHANGE): vethfcd015c: link becomes ready
May 12 10:21:01 marvin kernel: [   65.048596] br-7eb901c13937: port 4(vethfcd015c) entered blocking state
May 12 10:21:01 marvin kernel: [   65.048597] br-7eb901c13937: port 4(vethfcd015c) entered forwarding state
May 12 10:21:01 marvin kernel: [   65.117033] ata2: SATA link up 6.0 Gbps (SStatus 133 SControl 300)
May 12 10:21:01 marvin kernel: [   65.119121] ata2.00: supports DRM functions and may not be fully accessible
May 12 10:21:01 marvin kernel: [   65.120914] ata2.00: supports DRM functions and may not be fully accessible
May 12 10:21:01 marvin kernel: [   65.122321] ata2.00: configured for UDMA/133
May 12 10:21:01 marvin kernel: [   65.122340] ata2: EH complete
May 12 10:21:01 marvin kernel: [   65.135296] ata2.00: Enabling discard_zeroes_data
```

---

```
May 12 10:21:42 marvin kernel: [  105.460013] ata2.00: exception Emask 0x10 SAct 0x0 SErr 0x400100 action 0x6 frozen
May 12 10:21:42 marvin kernel: [  105.460018] ata2.00: irq_stat 0x08000000, interface fatal error
May 12 10:21:42 marvin kernel: [  105.460021] ata2: SError: { UnrecovData Handshk }
May 12 10:21:42 marvin kernel: [  105.460024] ata2.00: failed command: WRITE DMA EXT
May 12 10:21:42 marvin kernel: [  105.460028] ata2.00: cmd 35/00:00:38:36:31/00:0a:28:00:00/e0 tag 19 dma 1310720 out
May 12 10:21:42 marvin kernel: [  105.460028]          res 50/00:00:e7:15:d9/00:00:26:00:00/e0 Emask 0x10 (ATA bus error)
May 12 10:21:42 marvin kernel: [  105.460032] ata2.00: status: { DRDY }
May 12 10:21:42 marvin kernel: [  105.460036] ata2: hard resetting link
May 12 10:21:42 marvin kernel: [  105.774643] ata2: SATA link up 6.0 Gbps (SStatus 133 SControl 300)
May 12 10:21:42 marvin kernel: [  105.776825] ata2.00: supports DRM functions and may not be fully accessible
May 12 10:21:42 marvin kernel: [  105.778751] ata2.00: supports DRM functions and may not be fully accessible
May 12 10:21:42 marvin kernel: [  105.780215] ata2.00: configured for UDMA/133
May 12 10:21:42 marvin kernel: [  105.780225] ata2: EH complete
May 12 10:21:42 marvin kernel: [  105.791444] ata2.00: Enabling discard_zeroes_data
```

---

```
May 12 10:21:50 marvin kernel: [  113.896069] ata2.00: exception Emask 0x10 SAct 0x0 SErr 0x400100 action 0x6 frozen
May 12 10:21:50 marvin kernel: [  113.896083] ata2.00: irq_stat 0x08000000, interface fatal error
May 12 10:21:50 marvin kernel: [  113.896093] ata2: SError: { UnrecovData Handshk }
May 12 10:21:50 marvin kernel: [  113.896102] ata2.00: failed command: WRITE DMA EXT
May 12 10:21:50 marvin kernel: [  113.896115] ata2.00: cmd 35/00:00:00:f2:36/00:06:28:00:00/e0 tag 14 dma 786432 out
May 12 10:21:50 marvin kernel: [  113.896115]          res 50/00:00:ff:f1:36/00:00:28:00:00/e0 Emask 0x10 (ATA bus error)
May 12 10:21:50 marvin kernel: [  113.896128] ata2.00: status: { DRDY }
May 12 10:21:50 marvin kernel: [  113.896137] ata2: hard resetting link
May 12 10:21:51 marvin kernel: [  114.210830] ata2: SATA link up 6.0 Gbps (SStatus 133 SControl 300)
May 12 10:21:51 marvin kernel: [  114.213040] ata2.00: supports DRM functions and may not be fully accessible
May 12 10:21:51 marvin kernel: [  114.215030] ata2.00: supports DRM functions and may not be fully accessible
May 12 10:21:51 marvin kernel: [  114.216557] ata2.00: configured for UDMA/133
May 12 10:21:51 marvin kernel: [  114.216575] ata2: EH complete
May 12 10:21:51 marvin kernel: [  114.222011] ata2.00: Enabling discard_zeroes_data
May 12 10:21:51 marvin kernel: [  114.296031] ata2: limiting SATA link speed to 3.0 Gbps
May 12 10:21:51 marvin kernel: [  114.296034] ata2.00: exception Emask 0x10 SAct 0x0 SErr 0x400100 action 0x6 frozen
May 12 10:21:51 marvin kernel: [  114.296039] ata2.00: irq_stat 0x08000000, interface fatal error
May 12 10:21:51 marvin kernel: [  114.296042] ata2: SError: { UnrecovData Handshk }
May 12 10:21:51 marvin kernel: [  114.296045] ata2.00: failed command: WRITE DMA EXT
May 12 10:21:51 marvin kernel: [  114.296049] ata2.00: cmd 35/00:88:48:68:d8/00:09:26:00:00/e0 tag 23 dma 1249280 out
May 12 10:21:51 marvin kernel: [  114.296049]          res 50/00:00:47:68:d8/00:00:26:00:00/e0 Emask 0x10 (ATA bus error)
May 12 10:21:51 marvin kernel: [  114.296054] ata2.00: status: { DRDY }
May 12 10:21:51 marvin kernel: [  114.296057] ata2: hard resetting link
May 12 10:21:51 marvin kernel: [  114.611184] ata2: SATA link up 3.0 Gbps (SStatus 123 SControl 320)
May 12 10:21:51 marvin kernel: [  114.613520] ata2.00: supports DRM functions and may not be fully accessible
May 12 10:21:51 marvin kernel: [  114.615475] ata2.00: supports DRM functions and may not be fully accessible
May 12 10:21:51 marvin kernel: [  114.617036] ata2.00: configured for UDMA/133
May 12 10:21:51 marvin kernel: [  114.617057] ata2: EH complete
May 12 10:21:51 marvin kernel: [  114.633135] ata2.00: Enabling discard_zeroes_data
```

**Update #3**

The SATA data/power cable has been replaced, and time will tell us if that's the final fix.

Comment: Wow, thanks for the extensive reply! Updating the BIOS will take me a while as I want to make sure everything is properly backed up, but I'll get that done today. I have increased the swapfile size as recommended. I'm somewhat surprised it was ever swapping memory, I may just go and update the machine to have 32GB or 64GB, I was considering adding a RAM disk for transcoding purposes anyway.

I'm going to let the BIOS and swapfile changes soak for a week; if there are no crashes after that I will most certainly come back and checkmark this answer (or is it better etiquette to do it now?)

Comment: @max.dyckhoff Don't make any hardware changes right now, until we get some handle on the crashes/freezes. The BIOS and the swap may be all it needs. Keep me posted please. Accept my answer later, after we get it fixed, ok?

Comment: I have made the BIOS and swap changes, and I've also set up a little script that's logging the top 10 processes by memory usage from top. Thanks for your help, fingers crossed!

Comment: Unfortunately the machine just crashed again, in the same manner as before. The uptime wasn't even that long; I rebooted it last night at 6:30p PST to install some dist upgrades, and it crashed today at 12:17p PST. Are there any more logs etc that I can provide to help debug things even more? How am I supposed to attach logs to a post like this, I can't see a file upload anywhere, or do I just host it remotely and link to it? @heynnema

Comment: @max.dyckhoff  Show me what got created in /var/crash. Long log files can be posted at paste.ubuntu.com. Show me todays /var/log/syslog. I'll grab a cup of coffee and try to read though it.

Comment: paste.ubuntu.com wouldn't let me paste it because it was too large, but I've put it on my Dropbox for your perusal. Again I really appreciate your assistance, wish I could buy your cup of coffee!

https://www.dropbox.com/s/b6zm190ee46gcy9/syslog?dl=0

@heynnema

Comment: Looking now....

Comment: Still looking... a lot of veth entries. Edit your question and show me `cat /etc/network/interfaces` and `cat /etc/netplan/*.yaml`.

Comment: Are those veth entries network configurations from my Docker containers?

Comment: I think yes. I found a couple of things... heavy veth syslog activity... postconf/postfix errors... and ncq disk error... I'll put together a quick answer about the ncq error. If you `grep -i postfix /var/log/syslog*` you'll see that error(s). If you `grep -i FPDMA /var/log/syslog*` you'll see the ncq error (I saw one, there may be more).

Comment: @max.dyckhoff Take a look at my Update #1

Comment: Thanks, I have edited the grub config as suggested, server is rebooting. I don't know what a postconf/postfix error is, is that something I need to fix somehow?

Comment: Oh, I installed postfix to try playing with it a few months ago; I have removed it.

Comment: Postfix is mail.

Comment: @max.dyckhoff Any problem since the ncq patch? Please keep me posted. If after a few days it seems to work, please remember to accept my answer by clicking on the checkmark icon that appears just to the left of my answer. Thanks!

Comment: @heynemma No crashes in the last 24 hours fortunately; I'll keep you updated and will check the checkmark at the one week mark if things are going well! Thanks again for your help.

Comment: @heynemma Another day, another hang. It went offline at 5:55am this morning. Another syslog: https://www.dropbox.com/s/jmgwk66ga0ox5ma/syslog-20200512?dl=0

Comment: @max.dyckhoff Please see Update #2, and the comments that I've placed there.

Comment: @heynemma I have added the `therm` info as requested. I don't know how to fix the blocklayout issue, although note from the timestamp that it happens when I do the reboot, not before. The machine died at 5:55am, I reset it at 10:19am. I have fixed the issue in the docker override.conf file. I'll pull the SSD and check the firmware on my Windows PC later today. I'll also try and find some thermal paste and re-seat the CPU fan. The fan is definitely running whenever I check up on it, but perhaps there's some intermittent issue that I am not aware of. Thanks as always for your help.

Comment: @max.dyckhoff Thanks for the update. The therm command was to see if you had two different thermal control processes running, and you do. Purge thermald. The blkmapd process looks like it has something to do with nfs. Are you mounting any? Keep me posted. Thanks!

Comment: @heynemma I've done `apt remove thermald`, confirmed only one thermal control process is now running. I do have an NFS mount, to my NAS. It works fine though; I see various posts on the internet about that blkmapd error but no real resolution on how to fix it. I am increasingly thinking it's the SSD, either firmware or a hardware issue. Unfortunately it uses a proprietary SATA+power cable and I don't have a spare, nor have ASRock replied to my requests for extra. I may just try re-seating, see what happens.

Comment: @max.dyckhoff re: *"proprietary SATA+power cable"*... please describe.

Comment: @heynemma It's a cable that ASRock uses in the Deskmini series, you can find it if you Google "deskmini SATA cable", or I have uploaded some photos of it here: https://www.dropbox.com/sh/8djroq2yhlel16m/AAAT7pQc0XnGRGyCaYHPbREJa?dl=0

This morning I reseated the SATA cable and the CPU fan cable (I don't have thermal paste at present to reseat the fan itself, some will be delivered tomorrow though). Will keep you informed with how it's doing.

Comment: The more I think about it the more I suspect my issues started when I installed this hard disk. There's an M.2 NVME drive which holds all the system stuff, but I added a 500GB SATA SSD for data purposes.

Comment: @max.dyckhoff If reseating the sata cable doesn't help, if it'll reach, plug it into the other sata port on the motherboard.

Comment: @heynemma Been Googling the various ATA errors from syslog and the general consensus is a bad SATA cable. The SMART report for the drive also shows 280 UDMA_CRC_Error_Count, another indicator of a bad cable. I am hoping that this is the cause of the instability, I guess there's not really any way of knowing? 

I'll switch the cable to the other port on the motherboard later today and inspect if the errors in the syslog on startup go away.

Comment: @max.dyckhoff Funny thing... that's what I had put into my answer... giggle :-) Keep up the research!

Comment: @heynemma Plugged it into the alternate SATA port, same errors come up.. I may have another SSD lying around that I can try putting in there instead to see if similar errors arise. If not then I need to hope that ASRock gets back to me with a replacement SATA cable, or I try something else like buying a larger NVME drive and using that instead.

Comment: A super weird thing is that these errors occur at the 1 minute mark of boot (from what I understand of syslog). I was able to ls a directory on that drive and edit a file on it before these errors appeared in the log.

Comment: @max.dyckhoff Have you checked the firmware yet?

Comment: @heynemma Just updated the firmware, it was a revision behind it seems. Reconnecting the drive to the server and it still throws the same errors in syslog on start. I'll have to dig in some boxes to see if I can find a spare SSD and identify if that repros the errors.

Comment: @max.dyckhoff Have you considered a power supply problem? What wattage rating is it? Is its internal fan operating?

Comment: Yeah the power supply is adequate; the machine is a Mini-STX, no GPU, no spinning drives, very few power requirements. There's also no fan on it, it's an external supply which feeds DC 120W to the device. I managed to get in touch with ASRock at last, and they are sending me 3 replacement SATA cables, hopefully very soon. I am solidly convinced that it's the drive issue at this point; I did some scraping of my chat logs and discovered that the issues started about two weeks after I installed the SATA SSD drive.

Comment: I replaced the SATA cable and am no longer getting any errors in my syslog on startup. I'm pretty confident that this will fix the issue, so I've marked your answer as correct. Is there anything else I need to do - such as edit my original post - to note what aspect of your answer was the ultimate solution?

Thanks again for all your help, I could not have done it without you, and I appreciate the time and effort you put into your answers.

Comment: @max.dyckhoff Thanks for the update! I've added another update to my answer. Please keep me posted. Thanks!

Comment: Sigh, it just crashed again. A mere three hours after I last started it up. Really at a loss for what could be wrong now.

Comment: @max.dyckhoff upload the current syslog and kern.log and tell me what time it went down, and I'll take another look. You can un-accept my answer until we fix it.

Comment: kern.log: https://www.dropbox.com/s/hoj8e4ixtacfeho/kern.log-20200519?dl=0
syslog: https://www.dropbox.com/s/yj0h0wj851bwtw5/syslog-20200519?dl=0

It died around 15:53:11, and I rebooted it at 16:11

Comment: @max.dyckhoff The only thing I see in the logs is overtemps on the CPUs. Do `grep -i temperature /var/log/kern.log` and you'll see what I see. This looks so much like a cooling problem, or a power problem. Is this server plugged into a UPS? If so, do you have apcupsd running?

Comment: It's not plugged into a UPS, although I do have one lying around I could use. There's no obvious temporal relationship between the temperature spiking and the machine hanging; could it be that it just didn't have the time to log it before it hung?

Comment: @max.dyckhoff Sure. Plug it into the UPS. Can't hurt. Did you see all of the temp warnings in kern.log? Something ain't right. One trick we used in the computer repair business is to run the machine, and take the plastic handle of a screwdriver and tap on the motherboard, power supply, etc. to see if we could force an error. You might try that. `cause there's nothing in the log files that even gives any clue... other than the temp errors.

Comment: @max.dyckhoff If it's an APC UPS, install apcupsd, a data cable to a USB port, configure apcupsd, and it'll log errors to syslog.

Comment: I believe it is an APC UPS, will dig it out after dinner. The space where this device lives is pretty tight (and potentially insufficiently ventilated, hence temperature issues!), but I think I can get the UPS in there. A future goal is to improve the ventilation in there, but until then I can just leave the door open to help it cool.

Comment: Sadly I can't find my UPS, I just moved and so it's probably hiding in a box somewhere. I have reseated the CPU fan though, the thermal paste looked like it wasn't very evenly applied. CPU temps are now about 5-7C lower than before which is a good sign. They were in the low 40s, now they are in the low-mid 30s.

Comment: Just as a late update, I went and installed fans in the media cupboard and the temp in there went and got nice and stable, and STILL crashes. Finally realised that the motherboard is only rated for a 65W processor, and I was using the 6700K which is 95W. Bit the bullet and upgrading the motherboard and CPU to support an i7 9700, which is just 65W. THAT should make it stable. Any idea if I can just plug the old SSD into the new machine and it'll all work seamlessly, or should I do a clean install?

Comment: @max.dyckhoff Thanks for the update! Good job on the continued troubleshooting! Go ahead and try to move over the SSD and see if it boots. Minor tweaks might be required, like for the network interfaces.